# Proving equality given continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration, trigonometry

[image]

For the first equality of the first one I can use the substitution $y=\pi/2-x$ but for the second equality how do I prove for instance that the function is symmetric at $\pi/2 $ so that holds true? For the second one, similarly do i prove that the cos function has a period of π so the equality holds true?

Comment: I am curious what continuity has to with the result?

Answer (score 0):

It is not symmetry of $f$ that you need.
For $x \in [\pi/2, \pi]$ we have $f(\sin x) = f(\sin (\pi - x))$ so you can relate $\int_{\pi/2}^\pi f(\sin x) \mathop{dx}$ to $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(\sin x) \mathop{dx}$.

Comment: So sub y=π -x and prove they are equal?